# I’m a billionaire that will time travel to the year 1100 CE with a shipping crate. How can I take over the world?

Tags: time-travel, history

I have recently bought a time machine. It’s capable of sending me as well as a shipping crate full of items back to 1100 CE.

- I have one year to prepare and learn any skills that will help me
- I will travel back to the year 1100, give or take a few decades 
  -I will be arrive in some part of England, no idea of the exact location 
  -My time machine will create an alternate timeline, so I don’t have to worry about affecting the present
- The journey is one way and I am the only person that can go
- I am also able to bring a shipping crate with me that I can fill with whatever might help me
- I have a year to learn anything that might help me.
- the time machine will take care of translation, so I don’t have to worry about learning a new language
- I am a billionaire, so basically any good that can be produced I can bring with me. Money is no object I am only limited by production
- I know that I will not appear in direct view of anyone and will be a days walk away from a village
- I don’t need to bring an actual shipping crate, it’s just the upper limit of goods I can bring with me
- I don’t want to draw any unnecessary attention to myself, so my crate should be disguised as something
- I’m 18 years old and healthy, so I will likely have a lifetime of living before I die

Given all of this, I have three questions

1. what should I bring with me and how can I disguise it?
2. What skills should I learn over the next year of preparation? Assume that I’m spending all day every day learning.
3. What should be my game plan upon arriving. I want to take over the world.

Keep in mind, I am not concerned with advancing humanity, though I am not opposed to it. My primary goal is to amass as much power as possible.

Note: I did some googling and I don’t believe this question has been asked before. If it has I’ll delete. I’ve just seen a ton of questions focused on ‘average joes’ arriving in the past with no prep I am interested in what a person could do if they did have the time and resources to prepare

Edit: the third part of my question is optional and can be as small or as detailed as you like. A commenter has pointed out that this part could be too broad, I am just hesitant to remove it as I do also want some basic strategies to use in the 1100s. I don’t need a detailed description just I guess an explanation on how these skills/goods could be used in the 1100s.

Edit 2: I am not doing this by choice. I have to time travel for whatever reason. Another answer addressed the fact that doing this would not be very fun. So I am adding this edit to remove the discussion on *why* a billionaire would choose to do something like this

Comment: *"What should be my game plan upon arriving. I want to take over the world."*  I think this pushes your question outside the scope we allow - it's basically us writing your story/plot, not you.

Comment: I added an edit to address this problem. Do you still think the question is too broad @StephenG

Comment: I'd say it was less of a problem (for me).

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: "*I’m 18 years old and healthy, so I will likely have a lifetime of living before I die*" - 
 The time-traveler seems likely to die sooner than they think due to smallpox, malaria, robbers, food poisoning, contaminated water, sepsis, and many other reasons that nobody is immune to.

Comment: This is very true I just want to assume for the purposes of this question that I will have a lifetime to complete my goals

Comment: ;) I think the point was rather that your "lifetime" will most likely be measured in weeks, not decades.

Comment: @user535733, more than the traveler die of some disease, he/she will be a walking biological weapon killing everyone else. =D

Comment: Start world domination planning to done it in time of one generation in England in 12th century looks like a bad idea. Take good glimpse about the future mongol expansion to Saladin in Egypt and win the grace of Mameluke Sultan! In his court knowedge was well considered.

Comment: Trying to take over the world in a period where England is just about forming into a single country. Probably not the best time to be aiming for. I'd jump in at the head of the age of exploration and make sure I was in a position to take over either India or the Americas via a trading company.

Comment: Is the billionaire a man or a woman? Aiming to become Pope or Patriarch of Constantinople would not work for a woman. Aiming to become the mistress of someone powerful is not so good for a man.

Comment: @Separatrix England became a single country under the Wessex dynasty, the descendants of Alfred the Great. William the Conqueror conquered it as a single country in 1066.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, my unmentioned point there is England was centuries ahead of the curve on unification from lots of little kingdoms, it's not really a valid period in history to try taking over the world.

Comment: @Separatrix While the world might be a bit over-ambitious, before the question was closed, and assuming a male billionaire, I was sketching out a plan to become Pope, then manipulate the crusades to obtain control of the Middle East.

Answer (score 5):

So - you are a megalomaniac who is willing to do without indoor plumbing, internet and modern medicine in order to get power.  In very broad strokes, you need to take over an existing church and kingdom and get them to take over the world for you by bribing them with the location of people the church can convert and resources that can be plundered.  The things to study are:

- History - detail of the personalities of all the key players everywhere on the planet for the period 1100 - 1130.  Get the stuff that isn't known at the time but has been dug up by historians since (but don't assume the historians got it all correct).  Find out who's secretly sleeping with whom, who has intelligence and ambitions etc.  You also need very detailed knowledge of the weather in your starting area for a year or so after your date of arrival.  Note that all of this information (weather and people) will become less accurate as the changes you make alter the timeline.
- Natural resources - you need to know who is producing what to set up trade routes that do not yet exist.  Most importantly, you need to have the location of every valuable / strategic mineral deposit that can be mined with 12th century technology everywhere in the world that is not discovered before about 1150.  This information can be relied on for the duration of your lifetime, the only risk is that someone may independently discover a resource's location before you reveal it.
- Economics - you need to know how to use the information on natural resources to build an empire based on trading and looting that will not collapse prematurely because of gluts of some materials and shortages of others.  For example, if you just focus on revealing the location of all the gold but no iron then the gold may be devalued but there will be insufficient working metal to allow the empire to expand.
- Shipbuilding and navigation - the biggest limit on taking over the world is letting your empire travel around it.  You need to crank up their maritime capabilities, meaning more efficient hulls and sails and better navigation techniques.  This is probably the only area of technology that you will have time to spend uplifting the local population with other than basic hygiene principles.
- Psychology - you need to be able to use all of the above knowledge to get other people to do stuff but let you not only avoid being burned as a witch/warlock but end up on top of the heap.  Good luck with that.

So what to put in the shipping container?  Enough camping gear, food etc to keep you alive until you can insert yourself into a position of power.  Some trade goods to get you started.  Mostly, hardcopy of all the information from the study areas above, stored on durable media in weather-resistant containers that are encoded so only you can read it all.  Prototypes of compasses, sextants etc that can be replicated with 12th century technology and possibly crucial tools for manufacturing those items only.

However, one note - you are unlikely to enjoy or survive the experience.  We have very limited knowledge at the detailed, able-to-produce-a-vaccine level of the diseases that existed at that time, so it is highly likely that you will die of a disease that your body has no resistance to and/or the people you interact with will die of the diseases in your modern body.  Social distancing may help, but that may not be feasible while ingratiating yourself and may remove some perks of your position as ultimate ruler.

Answer (score 2):

I can see no reason why someone living in the luxury and power available to billionaires in this modern age, would ever travel into the past.  Consider the following...

- Even world leaders, emperors and kings, born before 1596, had no indoor plumbing.
- Those born before 1802 had no electric lights.
- Television? 1927
- Air conditioning?  1902
- Refrigeration?, 1750

Even if you could fit these essentials (a composting toilet, a generator, a refrigerator/freezer and a smart television with a massive hard-drive stored movie & music collection) into your shipping crate, it still wouldn't make up for the fact that the best medical professional you can hire in the past won't even know what a disease is.

Stay in the present and enjoy being a billionaire!   Believe me, you already have more effective power than any history figure has ever had.

Comment: I appreciate your comment and this is very correct. I edited my question a bit as this line of reasoning isn’t something I really want to explore in this question. Still a very good and valid answer

Comment: You had me convinced at "indoor plumbing". :-)

Comment: The indoor plumbing one isn't totally true.  Many wealthy Romans had running water.  The biggest factor preventing most people in history from having running water wasn't technology, it was wealth and social complexity.  Most pre-modern societies just weren't rich or organized enough to provide running water for daily use.

Comment: Well, he's rich --- he just has to hire people to make a toilet and to keep the cistern filled. At least then, he'll have a comfy seat for when the inevitable diarrhea sets in.

Answer (score 1):

**Knowledge**

In the present day, hire the staff of a major university to amass a collection of digital videos covering all major branches of science, medicine and engineering.  Have them include all supporting materials with the goal of taking a group of preschool age children through several decades of digitally recorded lectures, turning them into 21st century college graduates with a variety of practical/applicable degrees.

Now that you have the knowledge base ready, armor your shipping trailer such that it is proof against any period melee and siege weapons, line the roof with solar panels to recharge the batteries for the educational computers, and add all the essential items from my previous answer (composting toilet, generators, refrigerator, etc.).   Finally, fill all remaining space with the best engineers, builders and warriors that money can buy along with the tools of their respective trades (plus plenty of spare parts and ammo).

Nobody said the contents of the trailer had to be inanimate.  The best thing you can bring with you into the past is a competent staff and a small army; along with the equipment and digital recordings necessary to make more of both staff and warriors.

As for what you should learn during your preparatory year, I would suggest diplomacy.  You are about to take a journey with a lot of powerful people whose skills and talents will be much more valuable in the new environment than the wealth and status you left behind.  So learn how to foster loyalty in your team mates and the children you raise/educate.  Otherwise, you may not be heading back in time to start your own bid for world dominance...  You might just be transporting your usurper back in time so that he can start his bid.

Be careful who you choose to include in your shipping container!

Comment: It is a shame this story got closed.  I have thought up a great third answer which focuses on the details of choosing who to put in the shipping container.  Finding skilled people with sick family, ugly divorces and legal issues and using your billions to fix their modern day lives, before inviting them to join you in the past.  If anything can earn loyalty from your staff once you leave your fortune and power behind in the future, it is the kindness your present day powerful self can show them and their loved ones today.